# Laravel 5.4:file upload to into aws s3 directly to bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I am trying to upload a file to AWS s3 bucket

```
public function fileTest(Request $request)
  {

      //this will create folder test inside my bucket and put the contents
      $request->file->store('test','s3');
  }
```

But the above code will create a folder named `test` inside my bucket and put the file into it.

But i want to directly upload to the bucket

```
$request->file->store('s3');
```

I've tried above code but dosen't worked.

Comment: you can check this solution. i have detailed explained.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105104/how-to-fix-upload-image-to-s3-using-laravel/61826028#61826028

Comment: you can check my solution that is easy and clear. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105104/how-to-fix-upload-image-to-s3-using-laravel/61826028#61826028

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my issue with following

```
  $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
  $s3->put('',$request->file);
```

**Shorthand**

`Storage::disk('s3')->put('',$request->file)`

Answer (score 2):

```
public function uploadFile (Request $request) {
    $file = $request->file('file');

    $imageName = 'uploads/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();

    Storage::disk('s3')->put($imageName, file_get_contents($file));
    Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($imageName, 'public');

    $url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($imageName);

    return Response::json(['success' => true, 'response' => $url]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Put your file on s3 server

```
    $agreement_contract_copy = $request->file('agreement_contract');
    $filename = $id. '/agreement' . '_' . time() . '.pdf';
    $student->agreement_copy = $filename;
    $student->save();
    Storage::disk('s3')->put($filename, file_get_contents($agreement_copy));
```

> If you can not define as public so default its store as private and when you use private method so in file geting time used temp method as below.
>   Get your file

```
Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl
    ($student->agreement_copy, \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5))
```

$student->agreement_copy

> Tested

Answer (score 0):

In a very short solution.

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put("destination_path", file_get_contents("BinaryResourse"));
```

Comment: more detail; please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105104/how-to-fix-upload-image-to-s3-using-laravel/61826028#61826028