# How to fix upload image to s3 using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I try to upload an image to s3 using Laravel but I receive a runtime error. Using Laravel 5.8, PHP7 and API REST with Postman I send by body base64
I receive an image base64 and I must to upload to s3 and get the request URL.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $s3Client = new S3Client([
        'region' => 'us-east-2',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => $key,
            'secret' => $secret
        ]
    ]);
    $base64_str = substr($input['base64'], strpos($input['base64'], ",") + 1);
    $image = base64_decode($base64_str);

    $result = $s3Client->putObject([
        'Bucket' => 's3-galgun',
        'Key' => 'saraza.jpg',
        'SourceFile' => $image
    ]);

    return $this->sendResponse($result['ObjectURL'], 'message.', 'ObjectURL');
}
```

Says:

> RuntimeException: Unable to open u�Z�f�{��zڱ��� .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `SourceFile` you have to use `Body`. `SourceFile` is a path to a file, but you do not have a file, you have a base64 encoded source of img. That is why you need to use `Body` which can be a string. More here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject

Fixed version:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $s3Client = new S3Client([
        'region' => 'us-east-2',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => $key,
            'secret' => $secret
        ]
    ]);
    $base64_str = substr($input['base64'], strpos($input['base64'], ",") + 1);
    $image = base64_decode($base64_str);

    $result = $s3Client->putObject([
        'Bucket' => 's3-galgun',
        'Key' => 'saraza.jpg',
        'Body' => $image
    ]);

    return $this->sendResponse($result['ObjectURL'], 'message.', 'ObjectURL');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SourceFile` parameter is leading to the *path* of file to upload to S3, not the binary

You can use `Body` parameter to replace the `SourceFile`, or saving the file to local temporary and get the path for `SourceFile`
Like this:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $s3Client = new S3Client([
        'region' => 'us-east-2',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => $key,
            'secret' => $secret
        ]
    ]);
    $base64_str = substr($input['base64'], strpos($input['base64'], ",") + 1);
    $image = base64_decode($base64_str);

    Storage::disk('local')->put("/temp/saraza.jpg", $image);

    $result = $s3Client->putObject([
        'Bucket' => 's3-galgun',
        'Key' => 'saraza.jpg',
        'SourceFile' => Storage::disk('local')->path('/temp/saraza.jpg')
    ]);

    Storage::delete('/temp/saraza.jpg');

    return $this->sendResponse($result['ObjectURL'], 'message.', 'ObjectURL');
}
```

---

And, if you're using S3 with Laravel, you should consider the S3 filesystem driver instead of access the `S3Client` manually in your controller

To do this, add the S3 driver `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`, put your S3 IAM settings in `.env` or `config\filesystems.php`

Then update the default filesystem in `config\filesystems`, or indicate the disk driver when using the Storage `Storage::disk('s3')`

Detail see document [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#driver-prerequisites)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to **uploads Any file in AWS-S3 Storage**.

First, check your ENV setting.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= your access key
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-south-1
AWS_BUCKET=your bucket name
AWS_URL=Your URL
```

The second **FileStorage.php**

```
  's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        //'visibility' => 'public', // do not use this line for security purpose. try to make bucket private.
    ],
```

Now come on main Code.
**Upload Binary File from HTML Form**.

```
 $fileName = 'sh_'.mt_rand(11111,9999).".".$imageFile->clientExtension();;
 $s3path  =  "/uploads/".$this::$SchoolCode."/";
 Storage::disk('s3')->put($s3path, file_get_contents($req->file('userDoc')));
```

> **Upload Base64 File**
> **For Public Bucket or if you want to keep file Public**

```
 $binary_data = base64_decode($file);
 Storage::disk('s3')->put($s3Path, $binary_data, 'public');
```

> **For Private Bucket or if you want to keep file Private**

```
   $binary_data = base64_decode($file);
   Storage::disk('s3')->put($s3Path, $binary_data);
```

I Recommend you keep your file private... that is a more secure way and safe. for this, you have to use PreSign in URL to access that file.

For **Pre sign-In URL** check this post. [How access image in s3 bucket using pre-signed url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926984/how-access-image-in-s3-bucket-using-pre-signed-url/63188006#63188006)

Comment: 'visibility' => 'public', is required . if anyone forget then add that else you can not get any upload ed file.

Comment: 'visibility' => 'public',  required in case of make file public else u can leave it. before it u hv to check nature of your bucket first.